# FluentMigrator automatic generating the migration c# code

Tags: c#, .net, database-migration, fluent-migrator

I'm using FluentMigrator to build and update database. But I need to make migration code manually. I would like to have ability generate this based on entities classes like it makes EntityFramework (code-first). Do we have any solution for this functionality? Or maybe you could advise me another migration system?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for doesn't exist in Fluent Migrator.